# How to put console output into .csv using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, output

I want to put wavelet coefficients to a .csv row from the console.

The code below can put only one digit to a .csv file

```
   def waveletdbbiorone(self):     #function for Wavelets computation
     for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif'):
     imgwbior = mahotas.imread (filename) #read the image
     arraywbior = numpy.array([imgwbior])#make an array for pywt module
     coefwbior = pywt.wavedec(arraywbior,'db1')#compute wavelet coefficients
     arr = numpy.array([coefwbior])
     np.set_printoptions(threshold=3)
     # print arr
  for elem in arr.flat[:50]:
    #print('{}\t'.format(elem))  #this code puts the result to console
    with open('сomput.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
      writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|',    quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
      writer.writerow([('{}\t'.format(elem))])
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are opening the file always with `w` (write mode), which automatically erases
the content:

Try this:

```
 with open('сomput.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
     for elem in arr.flat[:50]:
        #print('{}\t'.format(elem))  #this code puts the result to console

         writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|',    quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
         writer.writerow([('{}\t'.format(elem))])
```

#### one more addition, the preferred way to save arrays:

```
numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", array, delimiter=" ")
```

and flattening also works:

```
numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", array.flat[:50], delimiter=" ")
```